# execute a function once in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I have to check a list of array using for loop, then do ONE single function base on the result, like

```
    for(var i=0;i<settingData.length;i++){
        if(settingData[i].a !== '' && $scope.settingData[i].b){
save();
}else{
alert('missing fields');
}
}
```

how can I make the save() to execute once? because when I put an alert it will trigger few times because it's within a for loop. I can't take it out because I have to check through all of my array..

Comment: Do you mean that you want to exit the loop after `save()` has run?

Comment: @Pointy if the statement is true run save()

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.  What do you want to do when that `if` statement is `true` for two elements in the list?

Answer (score 3):

Add a `break` after you save function:

```
for(var i=0;i<settingData.length;i++){
    if(settingData[i].a !== '' && $scope.settingData[i].b){
        save();
        break;
    }else{
        alert('missing fields');
    }
}
```

Comment: but break; will not me loop through each of every i.

Comment: Dean, if my second array has empty property, the alert which located at the else scope will not trigger, so break is no good for this case.

Comment: Add a condition to test if your second array has empty property. And show the alert if its true.

Comment: whut? the i will loop through my array.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a missingFields variable.

```
var missingFields = false;
for(var i=0;i<settingData.length;i++){
    if(! (settingData[i].a !== '' && $scope.settingData[i].b) ) {
      missingFields = true;
      alert('missing fields');
      break;
    }
}
if (!missingFields) {
  save();
}
```

Comment: the save triggered and the alert will trigger if one of the array is not equal to `''`

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you only want to save if the alert is never shown?